# Calculated column Running MAX of values so far in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

Can you help me with how can I have a column in DAX to store the running MAX of values so far.

My table has two columns named as `DateTimeStamp` column and `Value` column and **I want to have a new column that shows me the MAX value so far in another column.**

[image]

Your kind guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See
Lots of articles and videos on this.  http://sqlbi.com is probably the most useful, comprehensive, and authoratitive site for help with DAX.

Read https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/computing-running-totals-in-dax/
So

```
Running MAX of value = 
  var MaxTimestamp = max( 'Table'[DateTimeStamp] )
  return calculate(
               max( 'Table'[Value] ),
               'Table'[DateTimeStamp] <= MaxTimestamp,
               ALL ( 'Table'[DateTimeStamp] )
           )
```

Comment: Thank you my friend but it is not what I’m looking for. if I use ‘max( 'Table'[DateTimeStamp]’ then it will use the max of the column DateTimeStamp. But i want to find the max Value until the current row not the last row of the culumn. As an example when in the row 4 i want to look for max from row 1 to 4. If in row 7 i want the max from row 1 to 7. So, as I mentioned previously if i wanted to have a measure then your formula works great but i want to create a calculated column not a measure.

Comment: It does that.  In I’ve measure the row scope is converted to a filter scope so Max returns the current row’s DateTime.